# Fortran cast 2D Array to 1D array and pass it

Tags: arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, fortran

I am working with Fortran 2008 with the Intel 17 Compiler.
I am getting a 3D (x,y,z) assumed shape array in a subroutine and want to pass xy slices as a 1D array to another function that multiplies it with a matrix:

```
SUBROUTINE xy_gyro_average_3d(this,infield,barfield)
    class(xy_GyroAverager_t) :: this
    REAL,DIMENSION(:,:,:), INTENT(IN),contiguous,TARGET :: infield
    REAL,DIMENSION(:,:,:,:,:), INTENT(OUT),contiguous,TARGET :: barfield

    INTEGER :: n,m,k,li0,lj0
    type(Error_t) :: err
    REAL,DIMENSION(:),POINTER :: inptr,outptr

    li0=SIZE(infield,1)
    lj0=SIZE(infield,2)
    DO n=1,this%ln0
        DO m=1,this%lm0
            DO k=1,this%lk0
                inptr(1:li0*lj0) => infield(:,:,k)
                outptr(1:li0*lj0) => barfield(:,:,k,m,n)
                CALL this%gyromatrix(k,m,n)%multiply_with(invec=inptr,&
                    &                                    outvec=outptr,err=err)
                if (err%err) call write_err(err)
            END DO ! k
        END DO ! m
    END DO ! n
END SUBROUTINE xy_gyro_average_3d
```

The multiply_with routine looks (simplified) like this:

```
SUBROUTINE multiply_with(this,invec,outvec,err)
    CLASS(Matrix_t) :: this
    real, dimension(1:), intent(IN) :: invec
    real, dimension(1:),intent(OUT) :: outvec
    CLASS(Error_t),INTENT(OUT) :: err

    CALL this%multiply_with__do(invec,outvec,err)

END SUBROUTINE multiply_with
```

I am getting a warning about the pointer allocation and then an error about the types of actual and dummy argument not matching:

```
src/GyroAverager.F90(294): warning #8589: Fortran 2008 specifies that if a bound remapping list is specified, data target must be of rank one.   [INFIELD]
            inptr(1:SIZE(infield(:,:,k))) => infield(:,:,k)
----------------------------------------------^
src/GyroAverager.F90(295): warning #8589: Fortran 2008 specifies that if a bound remapping list is specified, data target must be of rank one.   [BARFIELD]
            outptr(1:li0*lj0) => barfield(:,:,k,m,n)
----------------------------------^
src/GyroAverager.F90(297): error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.   [INPTR]
            CALL this%gyromatrix(k,m,n)%multiply_with(invec=inptr,&
-------------------------------------------------------------^
src/GyroAverager.F90(298): error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.   [OUTPTR]
                &                                    outvec=outptr,err=err)
```

Now I think the warning should not be a problem as long as the arrays infield and barfield are marked as contiguous (is there any way to do this to get rid of the warning messages though?).
What exactly is the problem with the error message? The pointers inptr and outptr have the same dimension as the dummy arguments invec and outvec. 
But I read that if you pass a pointer but do not receive it as a pointer the array it is pointing to is passed instead. So in the end is it still passed as a 2D array instead of a 1D or is the problem somewhere else?

It was working before when the header of the multiply_with routine looked like this:

```
SUBROUTINE multiply_with(this,invec,outvec,err)
    CLASS(Matrix_t) :: this
    class(*), dimension(1:),intent(IN) :: invec
    class(*), dimension(1:),intent(OUT) :: outvec
    CLASS(Error_t),INTENT(OUT) :: err
```

and then the routines called by multiply_with would get the type via a select type later. But I reduced the code as we are always working with real arrays.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I'm afraid I find the question hard to understand.  In particular the paragraph starting with "Now I think..." and "The pointer has the same dimension as the dummy argument but I read that if you pass a pointer but do not receive it as a pointer the array it is pointing to is passed instead".  I mostly see what you're asking but could you be precise on which pointer, which dummy argument, etc.?

Comment: The pointers inptr and outptr have the same dimension as the dummy arguments invec and outvec. Yet the compiler is still giving me the error message. The rest was about what I read in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188798/fortran-function-pointer-as-actual-argument-and-target-as-formal

Comment: Ah, so dummy argument of `multiply_with`, not `xy_gyro_average_3d`?  Note that it is _type_ not _rank_ (/dimension) the error relates to.  As I can't immediately see why that difference would be the case, it seems that something unexpected is happening.  Can you give a complete example we can look at.  Type definitions, etc.  See [mcve] for more.